# How to simplify logs and powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

Is there any way to simplify $(\log a)^{\log b} = c$?

And even this $(\log x)^y = z$?

And also this $(\log m)(\log n) = p$ (which is essentially $\log m^{\log n} = p$)

I was trying to simplify some other equations when I encountered this sort of thing.
I'm only 17, so I'm not extremely experienced at maths. You will probably have to explain whatever answer you have to me.

Also, by simplifying I do mean arrange in terms on each variable.

Comment: i think you need to clarify what exactly you mean by “simplification”. There are some terms that one cannot “squeeze” into terms with less operations — just as i.e. $x \sqrt[x]{x}$. I do not know of a general method to simplify terms as you gave.
By the way, welcome to Math.SE, and do not worry about your age; as long as you follow the site's policy, you will (or at least are supposed to) get the answer. If neccessary, other users might help you to elaborate the problem any further. And do not worry, age does not affect how your question will be answered ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word of warning is to remember first that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}\neq (a^b)^{c}$, a common mistake when being faced with questions like this.

In truth, the ways you have written them already are about as pretty as you can make them look, however you are able to isolate one or more of the variables as you wish.  I will also make the assumption that here we are using the natural logarithm unless base is specified as a subscript, i.e. $\log x = y \Leftrightarrow x = e^y$.  In what way you want to simplify the expressions depends on what variable you wish to isolate in the end.

$$(\log a)^{\log b} = c\\ \log((\log a)^{\log b}) = \log c \\ \log b \cdot (\log \log a) = \log c\\
\log \log a = \frac{\log c}{\log b} = \log_b c\\
\log a = e^{\log_b c}\\
a = e^{(e^{\log_b c})}$$

---

For the second, $(\log x)^y=z$

$$(\log x)^y = z\\ y\cdot\log\log x = \log z\\ x = e^{e^{\frac{\log z}{y}}}\\
x = e^{e^{\log z^{\frac{1}{y}}}} = e^{(z^{\frac{1}{y}})}$$

---

As for $(\log m)(\log n) = p$

$$(\log m)(\log n) = p\\ \log m = \frac{p}{\log n}\\ m = e^{\frac{p}{\log n}}$$

---

Again, I doubt that these will be any cleaner or easier to use than what you already had.  There are no "*nice*" simplifications such as $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$ or $a \log b = \log (b^a)$.

Comment: Ah thanks for the answer. Well described and good step-by-step working. And yes, by simplify I did actually mean rearrange in terms of each variable; you were right about that. And log logs! Wow, I have no idea how I didn't think of that. Thanks! Also, since I didn't write `ln` instead of `log`, why did you assume natural log? Is it to avoid using a number?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy Computer scientists and algorithms specialists commonly use $\log x = y \Leftrightarrow x = 2^y$, whereas physicists and chemists usually use $\log x = y \Leftrightarrow x = 10^y$.  Pure mathematicians on the otherhand often use $\log x = y \Leftrightarrow x = e^y$.  If you want to make sure you are understood, either specify which base you are using at the beginning or use subscript notation if it is not clearly understood from context.

Comment: Why does it matter? I understand for computers, but why does it matter for anything else? Won't you end up with the same answer?

Comment: $2^y\neq 10^y\neq e^y\neq 2^y$ unless $y=0$, so in each of the three fields, the ways they use "$\log x$" give different results.  To be precise it could be said instead that they often use $\log_2, \log_{10},$ and $\log_e$ respectively while often dropping the subscript.